# How to disable onDisconnect? - Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a code snippet below that adds a number to the database at a specific path if the user has logged out of the application.

I have a question, how can I make it so that onDisconnect does not fire as I wish? Is it possible?

```
DatabaseReference presenceRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("rooms/" + roomName + "/disconnectP1");
presenceRef.onDisconnect().setValue(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cancel any `onDisconnect` handler you registered by calling the function that is returned when you call `onDisconnect()`. From the documentation on [how `onDisconnect` works](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works):

```
OnDisconnect onDisconnectRef = presenceRef.onDisconnect();
onDisconnectRef.setValue("I disconnected");
// ...
// some time later when we change our minds
// ...
onDisconnectRef.cancel();
```

When applied to your code, that'd be:

```
DatabaseReference presenceRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("rooms/" + roomName + "/disconnectP1");
OnDisconnect onDisconnectRef = presenceRef.onDisconnect();
onDisconnectRef.setValue(1);
...
onDisconnectRef.cancel();
```